# Can "item_name" value form PayPal contain HTML tags?

Tags: parameters, paypal, donations

Is possible to add `<br />` tags into the value of `item_name` in a PayPal form donation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that should be fine. They won't be parsed however.